# CSS: How to make drop down children to at least fill parent width

Tags: css

Here's a simplified version of my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/5pDtY/):

What I'm trying to have is menu's children to at least be their parent width but can be longer.

So on my example, "Short" sub menu is fine but "LongerParentThere"'s is not.

I need to keep this code for table cells auto filling (except if there is another way to do):

```
#container {
    width: 350px;
}

#container > ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
}

#container > ul > li {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Menus won't have other sub-levels.

Is there a way to do this without JavaScript ?

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13774939/css-drop-down-menu-making-childern-at-least-the-width-of-parents), may be a solution to your problem.

Comment: He's using floating divs, where I need to keep the `display: table;` effect (except if it can be changed but I need the same filling behaviour)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could (almost) achieve what you you want by adding these lines to your existing CSS:

*Works in Chrome and IE, **not** FF.

(Keep reading for a "universal solution".)*

```
#container > ul > li { position: relative; }
#container > ul > li > ul { min-width: 100%; }
#container > ul > li > ul > li { white-space: nowrap; }
```

**EDIT 1**:
I also figured out that adding `#container > ul > li:hover { display: list-item; }` will make it work in FireFox and IE (at least >= 9), but **NOT** in Chrome (!).

**EDIT 2**:
With the help of a CSS hack (as found on **[this pages](http://perishablepress.com/css-hacks-for-different-versions-of-firefox/)**), I managed to get the code working in Chrome, FF and IE. Enclosing a CSS declaration in `@-moz-document url-prefix() {...}` causes that declaration to be understood (and applied) by FF only.

*"Universal" solution. (Works in Chrome, FF and IE.)*

```
#container > ul > li { position: relative; }
#container > ul > li > ul { min-width: 100%; }
#container > ul > li > ul > li { white-space: nowrap; }
@-moz-document url-prefix() { 
#container > ul > li:hover { display: list-item; }
}
```

See, also, this (*UPDATED*) **[short demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ExpertSystem/BKtEA/)**.

Comment: Managed to do the tricks with your code by adding a parent div filling the space, which become new relative: http://jsfiddle.net/BKtEA/5/ - thanks for helping

Comment: Always happy to help :) I updated my answer with an addition that makes the code work in FF and IE (but not Chrome). Still looking for that universal solution. Adding that extra `div` was the obvious "workaround", but I want to believe there is some "straightforward" solution out there, waiting to be found :D

Comment: @user2412631: OK, I believe I got it ! See my updated answer (I know your problem's solved with the `div`'s, but it is always a good thing to have extra options ;)).

Comment: Thanks, I'll pick yours hoping no problems with mobile or exotics browser or else I'll go to the `div` workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Make the first-level `li` element relatively positioned.
Then you can use for the submenu `ul` and `li` `width: 100%`

http://jsfiddle.net/5pDtY/6/

Comment: Thanks, but for some reasons it's working on Chrome, IE but not on FF (v21) where children are going wild.

Comment: Doesn't it truncate the Longer Children ?

Comment: hmm, it seems that firefox has a bug with `position: relative` when is displayed as `table-cell`. You must use `table-cell`? You could use `inline-block` or `block` then it would work

[buglink](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=35168)

Comment: Yes it has, didn't saw that "Longer Children" is going multi-line. I'm using `display: table` for filling + centring an unknown number of elements I'll have.

Comment: It's not a bug in Firefox actually. The CSS 2.1 specs "[9.3.1 Choosing a positioning scheme: 'position' property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#choose-position)" say: "*The effect of 'position:relative' on table-row-group, table-header-group, table-footer-group, table-row, table-column-group, table-column, table-cell, and table-caption elements **is undefined**.*". So even if all other browsers use this value as "expected", Firefox is not wrong in ignoring it.